# The Multiplier of a Biholomorphism of the Complex Projective Space at a Fixed Point

Tags: complex-analysis, reference-request, riemann-surfaces, automorphism-group, complex-manifolds

Let $Aut(\mathbb{C} \mathbb{P}(1))$ be the **Automorphism Group** of $\mathbb{C} \mathbb{P}(1)$ ($\mathbb{C} \mathbb{P}(1)=$ the **Complex Projective Space** of dimension **one**).

Let $T \in Aut(\mathbb{C} \mathbb{P}(1))$, i.e., $T:\mathbb{C} \mathbb{P}(1) \longrightarrow \mathbb{C} \mathbb{P}(1)$ is a biholomorphism.

Let $p\in \mathbb{C} \mathbb{P}(1)$ such that $T(p)=p$ (i.e., $p$ is a fixed point for $T$).

What is the **multiplier** of the biholomorphism $T:\mathbb{C} \mathbb{P}(1) \longrightarrow \mathbb{C} \mathbb{P}(1)$ at the fixed point  $p\in \mathbb{C} \mathbb{P}(1)$?

Comment: Are you asking for the *definition* of the multiplier? That should be $T'(p)$.

Comment: @MartinR yes, I am looking for the definition of the multiplier. Is it the derivative of $T$ at the fixed point $p$? Any recommend reference?

Comment: @MartinR you are totally right. I fixed the mistakes

Comment: Any feedback on the answer? Let me know if anything is unclear.

Comment: @MartinR of course, I will let you know.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following is taken from “§3. Fatou and Julia: Dynamics on the Riemann Sphere.” in [Milnor: Dynamics in one complex variable: introductory lectures](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/9201272).

Let $S$ be a Riemann surface, $f:S \to S$ a non-constant holomorphic mapping, and $f^{\circ n}: S \to S$ its n-fold iterate.

$n$ distinct points
$$
  z_0, z_1, \ldots, z_{n-1}, z_n = z_0
$$
are called a “periodic orbit” or “cycle” if $f(z_j) = z_{j+1}$ for $0 \le j < n$, the number $n$ is the “period.” If $S$ is the complex plane or a subset thereof then
$$
\lambda = (f^{\circ n})'(z_j) = f'(z_1)f'(z_2) \cdots f'(z_n)
$$
is the “multiplier” or “eigenvalue” of the orbit.

In the more general case of self-maps of an arbitrary Riemann surface the multiplier is defined using a local coordinate chart around any point of the orbit.

*In your case:* If we represent the complex projective line as extended complex plane $\hat{\Bbb C} = \Bbb C \cup \{ \infty \}$ then its holomorphic self-maps are exactly the rational functions (and the automorphisms are the rational functions of degree one, that are the Möbius transformations).

If $p \in \Bbb C$ is a fixed-point of $f$ then $\lambda = f'(p)$ is the multiplier. If $p=\infty$ is a fixed-point of $f$ then its multiplier is the derivative of $g(z) = 1/f(1/z))$ at $z=0$.